# Como usar las rutas relativas en Linux para abrir el explorador de archivos o leer un fichero con java

Tags: java, linux, archivo, rutas, jar

Hice un programa en java que puede abrir el explorador de archivos en la carpeta actual en la que se ejecuta el programa
En Windows funciona bien, el problema es que al usarlo en Linux me redirige directamente al home, y todas las rutas relativas las basa en el home.

Por ejemplo, en este codigo abro el explorador de windows en la carpeta actual donde se encuentra el archivo jar desde el que estoy ejecutando el programa:
En Windows Fuciona bien,pero en Linux solo me abre el home.

//metodo 1: usando getProperty para obtener la ruta desde la que se ejecuta el codigo

```
String sCarpetaActual = System.getProperty("user.dir");
File objetofile = new File(sCarpetaActual);
Desktop.getDesktop().open(objetofile);
```

//metodo 2: usando ruta relativa

```
String sCarpetaActual = ("./");
File objetofile = new File(sCarpetaActual);
Desktop.getDesktop().open(objetofile);
```

Lo mismo me pasa al leer o guardar ficheros, en windows me respeta las rutas relativas y guarda los ficheros dentro de la misma carpeta (o subcarpetas) pero en linux asume que se encuentra en el home.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un nuevo File de la siguiente manera.

```
File file = new File (".");
```

El **"."**  indica el directorio actual.

Comment: Gracias Carlos, pero sigue abriendo el home y no en el directorio actual. Sera una cuestion de configuracion de java o linux? entorno de variables tal vez?

Comment: Lo mejor es que utilices un `JFileChooser` para evitar ese problema. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html